# How to get just the desired field from an array of sub documents in Mongodb using Java

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

I have just started using Mongo Db . Below is my data structure .

It has an array of skillID's , each of which have an array of `activeCampaigns` and each `activeCampaign` has an array of `callsByTimeZone`.

What I am looking for in SQL terms is :

```
Select activeCampaigns.callsByTimeZone.label,
       activeCampaigns.callsByTimeZone.loaded 
from X 
where skillID=50296 and activeCampaigns.campaign_id= 11371940 
      and activeCampaigns.callsByTimeZone='PT'
```

The output what I am expecting is to get

```
{"label":"PT", "loaded":1 }
```

The Command I used is

```
db.cd.find({ "skillID" : 50296 , "activeCampaigns.campaignId" : 11371940,
"activeCampaigns.callsByTimeZone.label" :"PT" },
{ "activeCampaigns.callsByTimeZone.label" : 1 , 
"activeCampaigns.callsByTimeZone.loaded" : 1 ,"_id" : 0})
```

The output what I am getting is everything under `activeCampaigns.callsByTimeZone` while I am expecting just for `PT`

DataStructure :

```
{
   "skillID":50296,
   "clientID":7419,
   "voiceID":1,
   "otherResults":7,
   "activeCampaigns":
   [{
       "campaignId":11371940,
       "campaignFileName":"Aaron.name.121.csv",
       "loaded":259,
       "callsByTimeZone":
       [{
           "label":"CT",
           "loaded":6
       },
       {
           "label":"ET",
           "loaded":241
       },
       {
           "label":"PT",
           "loaded":1
       }]
   }]
}
```

I tried the same in Java.

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilder.start().and("skillID").is(50296)
                    .and("activeCampaigns.campaignId").is(11371940)
                    .and("activeCampaigns.callsByTimeZone.label").is("PT");

BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("activeCampaigns.callsByTimeZone.label",1)
                    .append("activeCampaigns.callsByTimeZone.loaded",1).append("_id", 0);

DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query.get(), fields);
String campaignJson = null;
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    DBObject campaignDBO = cursor.next();
    campaignJson = campaignDBO.toString();
    System.out.println(campaignJson);
}
```

the value obtained is everything under `callsByTimeZone` array. I am currently parsing the JSON obtained and getting only `PT` values . Is there a way to just query the `PT` fields inside `activeCampaigns.callsByTimeZone` .

Thanks in advance .Sorry if this question has already been raised in the forum, I have searched a lot and failed to find a proper solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMO writing mongodb queries in java is really tuff !

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing it, but you should not be using String manipulation (i.e. `indexOf`), the performance could be horrible.

The results in the `cursor` are nested Maps, representing the document in the database - a Map is a good Java-representation of key-value pairs.  So you can navigate to the place you need in the document, instead of having to parse it as a String.  I've tested the following and it works on your test data, but you might need to tweak it if your data is not all exactly like the example:

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    DBObject campaignDBO = cursor.next();
    List callsByTimezone = (List) ((DBObject) ((List) campaignDBO.get("activeCampaigns")).get(0)).get("callsByTimeZone");
    DBObject valuesThatIWant;
    for (Object o : callsByTimezone) {
        DBObject call = (DBObject) o;
        if (call.get("label").equals("PT")) {
            valuesThatIWant = call;
        }
    }
}
```

Depending upon your data, you might want to add protection against null values as well.

The thing you were looking for (`{"label":"PT", "loaded":1 }`) is in the variable `valueThatIWant`.  Note that this, too, is a DBObject, i.e. a Map, so if you want to see what's inside it you need to use `get`:

```
valuesThatIWant.get("label");  // will return "PT"
valuesThatIWant.get("loaded"); // will return 1
```

Because DBObject is effectively a Map of String to Object (i.e. `Map<String, Object>`) you need to cast the values that come out of it (hence the ugliness in the first bit of code in my answer) - with numbers, it will depend on how the data was loaded into the database, it might come out as an int or as a double:

```
String theValueOfLabel = (String) valuesThatIWant.get("label");   // will return "PT"
double theValueOfLoaded = (Double) valuesThatIWant.get("loaded"); // will return 1.0
```

I'd also like to point out the following from my answer:

```
((List) campaignDBO.get("activeCampaigns")).get(0)
```

This assumes that "activeCampaigns" is a) a list and in this case b) only has one entry (I'm doing `get(0)`).

You will also have noticed that the `fields` values you've set are almost entirely being ignored, and the result is most of the document, not just the fields you asked for.  I'm pretty sure you can only define the top-level fields you want the query to return, so your code:

```
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("activeCampaigns.callsByTimeZone.label",1)
    .append("activeCampaigns.callsByTimeZone.loaded",1)
    .append("_id", 0);
```

is actually exactly the same as:

```
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("activeCampaigns", 1).append("_id", 0);
```

I think some of the points that will help you to work with Java & MongoDB are:

- When you query the database, it will return you the whole document of
  the thing that matches your query, i.e. everything from "skillID"
  downwards.  If you want to select the fields to return, I think those will only be top-level fields.  See [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/) for more detail.
- To navigate the results, you need to know that a `DBObject`s are returned, and that these are effectively a `Map<String,
  Object>` in Java - you can use `get` to navigate to the correct node,
  but you will need to cast the values into the correct shape.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation on how cursor works. I have accomplished the same by using BasicDBList before posting this question. By doing that I am guessing I would be actually getting the entire callsByTimeZone Array and then parse it out, but my intention is to write a query which can directly get the element with label PT. I guess I need to change the schema to achieve the same. I have two options here, 1. to flatten out the collection by creating data for each TimeZone as a field under activeCampaigns(a.k.a activeCampaigns{callsByTZPacific{},callsByTZEaster{}}) etc or

Comment: 2.Create another collection for callsByTimezone

Comment: Don't use a separate collection, that's defeating the purpose of MongoDB; and your first option won't work because you're still going to retrieve all activeCampaigns - remember that "fields" filters by the top-level field.  What you probably want to look at is [the Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) - this gives you much greater control over the data that's returned.

Comment: For now, I am able to use $elemMatch to get array element one level down //db.campaignData.find({"skillID":50297},{activeCampaigns:{$elemMatch:{"campaignId":11433464}}}) . This is good but it is limited to only one level down . $elemMatch does nt support drilling down to an array elemnt of an array.

Comment: //Don't use a separate collection, that's defeating the purpose of MongoDb; Can you please share your thoughts on why should nt we go for a flat structure,when querying a nested structure is getting complex and sometimes not possible.

Comment: Remember that MongoDB does not do joins, so when you put things in a separate collection you can incur additional costs - every call to each collection will require a network call to the database.  Your data will not be associated with the parent data (clientID etc).  It does depend on your use-case, but it's not automatically the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing while loop from your Java code with below seems to give "PT" as output.

```
   `while(cursor.hasNext()) {
        DBObject campaignDBO = cursor.next();
        campaignJson = campaignDBO.get("activeCampaigns").toString();
        int labelInt = campaignJson.indexOf("PT", -1);
        String label = campaignJson.substring(labelInt, labelInt+2);
        System.out.println(label);
      }`
```